# .env and mail.php files won't update - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, xampp, laravel-5.1

I started a project a few months ago and set the configuration to send mail, everything works great. But now i want to change the sender email address, so i changed the configuration in the .env and mail.php files, but laravel just ignored the updates (still uses the old configuration to send mail). I cleared cache and restarted everything, I even deleted those files and laravel keeps sending emails with the deleted files configuration. What can i do?

*.env:*

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=someaddress@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

*config/mail.php:*

```
return [

    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'from' => ['address' => 'someaddress@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Some Name'],
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    'username' => 'someaddress@gmail.com',
    'password' => '******',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,

];
```

*Controller:*

```
Mail::send('emails.devolucion', ['datos' => $diet], function ($message) use ($diet){
        $message->to($diet['correo'], $diet['nombre'])->subject('Devolución');
});
```

I used to have another address instead of "someaddress@gmail.com", and laravel keeps using that old email address instead of the new one. It is ignoring the files updates.

Comment: By "mail.php" you mean "config/mail.php", right?

Comment: Please post your sample mail function for better understanding

Comment: Can we please see the `mail.php` and `.env` configuration you have, as well as the `Mail::send` function you are using? This will help us see what is going on.

Comment: I updated the question, @ArtisanBay

Comment: I updated the question, @James

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload` to regenerate your files. Everything looks fine to me from your files, but whenever I have an issue with updates not being reflected I use that as my go to. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: It didn't work.
"Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "C:\ProgramDa
ta\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version.
Generating autoload files"

Laravel is still using the old email address

Comment: Sorry, try php artisan config:clear and let me know if that does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your config files are being cached, and that Laravel is then reading them from the cache which is why your updates aren't being reflected.

We can tell Laravel to clear the cache and start afresh using this command:

`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I believe you are referring to "php artisan cache:clear". Am I correct ?

Comment: @ArtisanBay nope. `php artisan config:clear` removes the configuration cache file, which is likely to be the root of OP's problem. `php artisan cache:clear` just flushes the applications cache, however if `php artisan config:clear` doesn't work then it could be worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you very much, @James! You solved my problem! "php artisan config:clear" worked!

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Mail**

Comment out the from address inside the mail function (if you have one), then the value from the configuration will be automatically taken

```
Mail::send('emails.newuser', $mailData,
  function( $message) {
  //$message->from('feedback@example.com', 'No Reply');
  $message->to('user@example.com');
  $message->subject('Mail Subject');
});
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @ErickRamírez.. values look correct in configs and the controller. Could you give a try by changing the host to smtp.mailgun.org.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @ArtisanBay, "php artisan config:clear" solved the issue.

Comment: Happy that you found the solution.. Happy coding :)