# Laravel .env constants not working with mail.php

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, laravel-5.1

**The error:**

In my mail.php file, if I set

```
   'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER'),
```

and have this to my .env file:

```
    MAIL_DRIVER=log
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", 
with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required"
```

**The wonky work-around**

In my mail.php file, I have the following:

```
   'driver' => 'log',
```

works fine.

**The Conclusion**

My theory is that mail.php is not reading my .env file constant correctly, since replacing it with the actual string fixes the problem.  However, the defaults for this file all make use of .env constants, so I'm wondering **why are my .env constants not getting recognized in my mail.php file?**

**FYI**

In other files besides mail.php in the same app, I am using other .env constants that work just fine.  For instance, in my UserTableSeeder class, I have:

```
    factory(App\User::class, 1)->create([
        'email' => env('ADMIN_EMAIL'),
        'password' => Hash::make(env('ADMIN_PASSWORD')),
        'is_admin' => 1
    ]);
```

which successfully makes use of the below constants from my .env file:

```
ADMIN_EMAIL=xxxxxxx@yahoo.com
ADMIN_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

**I tried the below 2 php artisan commands** (php artisan cache:clear and php artisan config:clear), but "smtp" continued to output when "log" is what I have in my .env file:

```
04:52:54 Fri May 13 vagrant@homestead (email_notifications)  [130]
~/Code/myapp $   php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!

05:52:56 Fri May 13 vagrant@homestead (email_notifications)  [0]
~/Code/myapp $   php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.6.1 (PHP 7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> dd(env('MAIL_DRIVER'));
"smtp"
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye.

05:53:23 Fri May 13 vagrant@homestead (email_notifications)  [0]
~/Code/myapp $   php artisan cache:clear
Application cache cleared!

05:53:48 Fri May 13 vagrant@homestead (email_notifications)  [0]
~/Code/myapp $   php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.6.1 (PHP 7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>>  dd(env('MAIL_DRIVER'));
"smtp"
```

Comment: the `.env` might not be parsed correctly or something, try adding the second parameter on `.env('MAIL_DRIVER','log')` so it could default to log, start an `php artisan tinker` and dump the `env('MAIL_DRIVER')` what the output?

Comment: In tinker, dd(env('MAIL_DRIVER')); results in "smtp" as the output, where it says "log" in my .env file.  However, dd(env('ADMIN_EMAIL')); results in my correct email.  I did notice that if I change my email, I have to run php artisan cache:clear before the update shows up in tinker, but dd(env('MAIL_DRIVER')); still results in "smtp"!

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645663/env-and-mail-php-files-wont-update-laravel-5-1?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, I had seen that, but it actually does not fix my issue

Comment: Are you trying to run tests? If thats the case, try adding MAIL_DRIVER to the phpunit.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be default constants in the .env file that includes one for `MAIL_DRIVER=sftp`.  If you add additional values for the same constant, the FIRST constant is the one that will get defined.  Thus, make sure to have just 1 constant definition in your .env file, or at least have it be the 1st one if for some reason you want more than one constant in there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you have solved it or not yet. But I'll try to provide a way too simple solution.

**Short Answer:** You need to immediately reboot the application as and when you make changes in your `.env` file.

---

**Not So Long Answer:** It is happening because your `.env` file is already being accessed by the laravel application. If you make changes in your `.env` file while your application is running in your local machine, it will not recognize it instantly. You will have to shut down your entire laravel application and reboot it once using `$ php artisan serve`.

Doing so, it will definitely take up the environment constants and you will get the desired result.

Hope this helps you out. Happy coding. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I haven't solved this problem yet, although your answer may help.  Does `php artisan serve` shutdown as well as reboot the laravel application?  If not, how do I shutdown the Laravel app before rebooting it?

Comment: Just close your terminal and you are done.. That will shutdown your application. And then do `$ php artisan serve`..